# How do I block all calls from outside my contacts and play them a recording with instructions to text me instead?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, call

I get about 5 robocalls a day in spite of using robocall blocker apps.  They use a blacklist of caller numbers that is useless because robocallers always just spoof a random number. The only solution seems to be to either change my number, or block all calls from outside my contacts. Both are unattractive because they might prevent legitimate humans from contacting me.  So I want to play all calls from outside my contacts a recording instructing them to text me instead.

If there is not already an app for this, would it be possible to write one with the API that apple provides?

Comment: iOS 13 actually introduced a setting which will let you achieve this: Settings > Phone > Silence Unknown Callers; then just set your voicemail message